# How to integrate the Cucumber-Selenium scripts (written in typescript) with Jmeter for the performance testing

Tags: typescript, selenium, jmeter, cucumber

I have test automation project written in typescript. How I can integrated it with JMeter so I can also run performance testing? Also do I need some reporting tool or how I can get integrated results?

Answer (score 0):

This could be possible if you set proxy in combination with JMeter recording.
There is also blazemeter chrome extension but I've never used it before: https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206732579-The-BlazeMeter-Chrome-Extension-Record-JMeter-Selenium-or-Synchronized-JMeter-and-Selenium

Comment: Can you please give me more info, I am new in JMeter? Some sample or some video if you have?